# odoo 9 pos traceback not available product.product

Tags: odoo

odoo 9 pos traceback not available product.product

when cnnecting with admin original account there is no problem but when try to connect with another account I am getting this error :
"Odoo server error: traceback not available" .
Need help please

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue while loading POS UI with 15k products. After a reloading, things seem to be working as expected. I guess it's the product DB loading timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Just setup right access for your staff, your account is admin (with full access)
For other users ( POS staff ) verify that accounting and finance access on the configuration board is set to accountant.